Angular upgrade from 16 to 17 using ng update with specific version of @angular/cli
I recently encountered an issue while upgrading my Angular project. After specifying the upgrade to use Angular CLI version 17.3.4 (ng update @angular/core@17 @angular/cli@17.3.4), the CLI updates is telling me that the installed Angular CLI is outdated and says there is no matching version found for @angular-devkit/architect@0.1703.5
All dependencies are coming from Nexus and there is no 17.3.5 version available yet. It will be soon but not at this moment.
Here are the steps I've taken:
Running ng v in my project directory correctly shows Angular CLI 17.3.4.
Despite this, when I attempt to run other Angular CLI commands, I receive messages stating my CLI version is outdated.
Additional information:
I have tried clearing the npm cache and reinstalling the dependencies.
The main goal is to stick to Angular CLI version 17.3.4 due to specific project requirements.
Questions:
Has anyone else encountered this issue where the correct version shows up with ng v but still is flagged as outdated?
Is there a workaround to prevent the CLI from prompting an update or misreading the version as outdated?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I navigate this upgrade path.

Could you include the package.json & error you encounter on your post.

The official angular guide states that you should use ng update @angular/core@17 @angular/cli@17 and this will pick the latest CLI available automatically. Why are you specifying a particular CLI version instead?

You may also want to try rm -rf node_modules and rm package-lock.json before you try the command above again.

First make sure you updated zone.js 0.14+, typescript 5.2+ and you are at node -v 18+ and npm -v 10+.
Once you are able to do npm i with this versions proceed to migrate each major version individually one by one.
ng update @angular/cli@17

ng update @angular/core@17

Worked for me only this way :)
